# Are there systems in computer science where we have several logic systems working all at once and without isolation?

Tags: logic

Are there systems in computer science where we have several logic systems working all at once and without isolation? I am thinking there are system where subsystem A uses Paraconsistent logic, subsystem B uses Four-valued logic, and subsystem C uses ordinary logic, but the elements inside those subsystem don't interact with each other and thus all elements in different subsystems are isolated from each other. Are there systems where they're not isolated and elements from subsystem A can interact with an element with subsystem B using either A or B logic? What might be the applications?